# Rails why does a form helper ERB tag end early on closing a div - positioning issue with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, css, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having some bother with rails and twitter bootstrap.

I want the following.

A form where the input text field has the submit button next to it, on the same line / row on all devices except *xs* where the submit button should sit centered underneath the input text field.

I have the following code:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
   <%= form_for Invitation.new , html: { id: "signup-form" } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :recipient_email, :class => "form-control full-width", :placeholder => "enter email address" , :id=>"InputEmail"%>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
   <%= f.submit 'JOIN IN', :class=>"btn btn-cta", :id=>"gabetabtn"%>
    <% end %>   
  </div>

</div>
```

The nopadding css class is:

```
.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}
```

This results in the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-2">
   <form id="signup-form" class="new_invitation" action="/invitations" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="CbtvKKHfXTK/5giKwMYNskwmau9lX7pI9tEs7yx69dA5DHc3VEdIavvoOJEhtMZrQIgA4QQ4W7yaFLo0Vw3oEw==">
    <input class="form-control full-width" placeholder="enter email address" id="InputEmail" type="text" name="invitation[recipient_email]">
  </form></div>

  <div class="col-sm-2 nopadding">
   <input type="submit" name="commit" value="JOIN IN" class="btn btn-cta" id="gabetabtn">
  </div>

</div>
```

Which almost works except when I hit XS < 768 pixels, The input button drops onto the next line, but is not centered.

So my questions are:

1. Why does the form tag end early when my <%end%> is after the submit button.
2. How can I make the button center only on xs devices using bootstrap!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your form tag ends early because the html is illegal.   You can't have the form element open inside one div element and close inside another one.  To make the html valid you either need to move the form element to wrap both divs, or move the `<%end%>` inside the div the form is in and add a `form="signup-form"` attribute to the submit